# Using a List of a List as a Lookup Property for IEnumerable<T>.ToLookup()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have a class that looks like this:

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public List<string> PersonalEffects {get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<Person>`, and I'd like to use the `IEnumerable<T>.ToLookup()` and use the name of each effect as the key, with the characters that have that effect as the values.  Sample output:

```cs
Cutlass (the Effect)
Jack Sparrow (Person)
Will Turner

Pistol
Jack Sparrow
Hector Barbossa
Davy Jones
```

However, my LINQ-fu is failing me.  I can do this through a Dictionary and a number of ForEach loops, but it doesn't seem as clean (even though it does end up being the same thing).

How can I do this using `ToLookup()` in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
persons.SelectMany(p => p.PersonalEffects.Select(e => new { Person = p, Effect = e }))
       .ToLookup(o => o.Effect, o => o.Person);
```

What we 're doing here is essentially a join of persons and effects, creating person+effect pairs (where both specific persons and effects can appear in many pairs each), then grouping these pairs by effect and collecting the persons posessing each effect in an enumerable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will have to flatten the list first into  pairs. You can do this with a rarely used (at least for me)  [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534732.aspx) overload:

```
List<Person> people = ...
var lookup = people.SelectMany(p => p.PersonalEffects, 
                              (p, c) => new { Name = p.Name, Effect = c.Name })
                   .ToLookup(e => e.Effect, e => e.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

QueryComprehension syntax of the previous answers for the curious:

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup =
  (
    from p in people
    from e in p.PersonalEffects
    select new { Name = p.Name, Effect = e }
  ).ToLookup(x => x.Effect, x => x.Name);
```